# What is causing my values to be printed as #

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
-- Formatting purpose
SET LINESIZE 200
COLUMN 'Pharmaceutical Companies' FORMAT a25
COLUMN 'Drug Count' FORMAT a10

-- Code
SELECT PHARNAME AS "Pharmaceutical Companies", COUNT (tradename) AS "Drug Count"
FROM DRUG
GROUP BY PHARNAME
HAVING COUNT (TRADENAME) = (SELECT MAX ("Drug Count")
FROM (SELECT COUNT (TRADENAME) AS "Drug Count" FROM DRUG
GROUP BY PHARNAME));
```

Above this is my set of code to get certain values out of my database. However, the results printed are

```
Pharmaceutical Companies  Drug Count
------------------------- ----------
Medmed Shine              ##########
```

If i remove the formatting purpose, it will show

```
Pharmaceutical Companies       Drug Count
------------------------------ ----------
Medmed Shine                           14
```

I have tried adjusting the format size but it still displays as `########`

Comment: Why are you trying to use a text field format - A10 - for a number? How do you want the numeric value to be displayed? (Also, [see this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1308)).

Comment: `A...` is a wrong format, you need `9999999999` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF))

Comment: @AlexPoole new to sql, didn't know `a10` is for string only, thanks for the guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aXXX` formats columns as text, but you are printing numbers. You can use `9`s to format a column as a number, which also lets you use commas to separate thousands:

```
SET LINESIZE 200
COLUMN 'Pharmaceutical Companies' FORMAT a25
COLUMN 'Drug Count' FORMAT 999,999,999,999
```

Comment: thanks, sorry, i didn't know about that, i am very new to sql at the moment and was only taught using `a10` to do formatting, but i didnt know it was only for string